# Multiply two column from two different table and set them into another table using triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, sqlyog

I have 3 Mysql tables and I want to make one of the fields generated from multiplying two fields from two different tables. These are my tables:

> **ITEMS**

```
id_item |  price
1       |   20
2       |   30
3       |   50
```

> **DETAIL TRANSACTIONS**

```
id_trans(fk) | id_item | total_items
1            |    1    |     1
1            |    2    |     1
1            |    3    |     1
```

> **TRANSACTIONS**

```
id_trans |  total_price
1        |      100
```

A `total price` field inside **TRANSACTIONS** is what I wanted, and I have tried making a trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER total_price
AFTER INSERT ON detail_transactions
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE transactions
   SET transactions.`total_price`= 
    (SELECT SUM(items.'price'*detail_transactions.'total_items') 
       FROM items
       JOIN detail_transactions
      ON items.'id_item'= detail_transactions.`id_item`)
 WHERE transactions.`id_trans` = NEW.`id_trans`;
```

But the result is not what I wanted. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Key words are FOR EACH ROW - ie update 1 row at a time..And do not assume transaction exists test and create if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key words are FOR EACH ROW - ie update 1 row at a time..And do not assume transactions exists test and create if need be

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on detail_transactions
for each row begin
    if not exists (select 1 from transactions t where t.id_trans = new.id_trans) then
        insert into transactions 
            select new.id_trans,new.total_items * price
            from items 
            where items.id_item = new.id_item ;
    else
        update transactions join items on items.id_item = new.id_item
            set total_price = total_price + (new.total_items * price);
    end if;
            
end $$
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_update_total_price
AFTER INSERT 
ON detail_transactions
FOR EACH ROW
REPLACE INTO transactions (id_trans, total_price)
    SELECT NEW.id_trans, SUM(items.price * detail_transactions.total_items) 
    FROM items
    JOIN detail_transactions USING (id_item)
    WHERE transactions.id_trans = NEW.id_trans;
```

This query assumes that `transactions (id_trans)` is defined as `UNIQUE` (maybe `PRIMARY KEY`).

If the row for this `id_trans` already exists it will be replaced with new values. If it not exists then it will be inserted.

The trigger creation statement contains 1 statement, so neither BEGIN-END nor DELIMITER needed.